# How to boil away water from a sauce without it splashing?

Tags: sauce, boiling, slow-cooking

When "slow cooking" a certain recipe, I need to keep a lid on the pot, or the sauce slowly but surely splashes all over the place.

However, with the lid on, the sauce retains much more water than I like.

How can I boil away the excess water, or otherwise make the sauce less watery, without incurring significant extra cleaning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If, when reducing a sauce, you are getting splashing outside the pot, your pot may be too small for the application.  Use a larger pot:  a wider base will allow more surface area for evaporation, and higher sides will make it harder for the content to get out.

You can also purchase a splatter guard, which is like a flat sieve or mesh that you can place over the top of the pot to reduce splatter without blocking air flow

[image]

although these are more typically used to reduce the splatter from frying.

Answer (score 1):

Partially cover your pot with its lid. To keep the lid partially open, you can put a wooden-spoon, or other non-metallic utensil is the pot so the lid rests on it.

Like so: http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6064/6052520487_75d3e74455_z.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can also partially put the lid on so it covers the top but allows the steam to escape.  If the splatter is violent, turn the heat down a bit so the bubbles are less energetic, but still present.